# iOS - Wrong size on iPhone 6 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, constraints, uistoryboard

I have inserted a `UILabel` in the `UIStoryBoard` centered horizontally. But when I run it on iPhone 6 it's not in the center. Why that happening and how I can prevent for facing the same problems on the future?

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

On other simulators like iPhone 5 that is working just fine.

Comment: Use autolayout and pin the label at the center

Comment: Did you set constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different resolutions for iOS devices, especially after the release of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. Because the storyboard is just a general representation of your application's interface, the size of canvas does *not* actually resemble any one particular screen size. In fact, you may notice that the default canvas is kind of like a "square."

As a result, you cannot expect your views to look exactly the same on simulators or actual devices as in your canvas by simply put all of them in your canvas. To layout, you need to use the *constraints*, which are a set of rules that explicity tell the system how you want to position your views. In fact, starting from iOS 8, Apple encourages developers to utilize `auto layout` and `size classes` to develop apps that fit on screens of *any* size, even iPhones and iPads at the same time.

---

In your case, in order to put the label in the center of the screen using constraints, just <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag your label to its super view in storyboard:

[image]

In the popover, choose both **Center Horizontally in Container** and **Center Vertically in Container**. You can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple constraints at one time. Then, in the **Size Inspector**, make sure that the constants of your constraints are `0`.

[image]

---

Please check out [Apple's guide about using AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), as it's the primary layout mechanism you will be using when developing iOS apps (or OS X applications) in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First  of all select label and use Pin tool to add top, width, height contraint:

[image: Pin]

Then, use Align property to align it horizontally :

[image: Align]

**P.S** - Learning auto layout is a very tedious thing, but once you get familiar to it, you'll find easy to create views for multiple devices. Look for tutorials and videos. Practice-Practice!

Answer (score 0):

-Select View Controller in Storyboard.
-Mark check on "Use Auto Layout option" in File Inspector in utility area.
-Select the label and add constraints for that label by clicking pin button bottom of the editor area.

Hope it will works for you.Thank you.